# in app purchases - device crash

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

if i run my app in the simulator  it says failedTransaction...

and if i run it  on my iPhone  it crashes with this error:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSSetM addObject:]: object cannot be nil'

here: is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:  (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

SKProduct * product = (SKProduct *) _products[indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = product.localizedTitle;
[_priceFormatter setLocale:product.priceLocale];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [_priceFormatter stringFromNumber:product.price];


if([[ScoreboardIAPHelper sharedInstance] productPurchased:product.productIdentifier]) {

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    cell.accessoryView = nil;
} else {
    UIButton *buyButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    buyButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 72, 37);
    [buyButton setTitle:@"Buy" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    buyButton.tag = indexPath.row;
    [buyButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buyButtonTapped:)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    cell.accessoryView = buyButton;
}

return cell;
}

- (void)buyButtonTapped:(id)sender {

UIButton *buyButton = (UIButton *)sender;
SKProduct *product = _products[buyButton.tag];

NSLog(@"Buying %@...", product.productIdentifier);
[[ScoreboardIAPHelper sharedInstance] buyProduct:product];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(productPurchased:) name:IAPHelperProductPurchasedNotification object:nil];



}
```

and i get my error here:

```
- (void)provideContentForProductIdentifier:(NSString *)productIdentifier {

[_purchasedProductIdentifiers addObject:productIdentifier];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:productIdentifier];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:IAPHelperProductPurchasedNotification object:productIdentifier];

 }
```

Comment: Which line of code is the error happening on?

Comment: The error you have posted is pretty specific.  You are trying to add a nil object to a mutable array.  In the code you posted, you should probably check to make sure that `productIdentifier` is not nil

Comment: the error only happens if i run the app on my iPhone and not in simulator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[__NSSetM addObject:]: object cannot be nil
```

This means that you have a mutable set that you are calling `addObject:` on, but the variable you are passing in is `nil`.

In the code you post, the only place you call this is in the line:

```
[_purchasedProductIdentifiers addObject:productIdentifier];
```

...so wherever you are calling `provideContentForProductIdentifier:`, you are passing it `nil`.

Comment: how come it only dos it on my phone  not in the simulator, there it just cant restore product Purchased.

Comment: You haven't provided enough code to determine that, but if I had to guess, I'd say that you are loading the product identifiers from an external file, and the case you used for the filename in code doesn't match the case you used for the actual filename.  iOS is case-sensitive, OS X is not.  Since it can't find the file, you end up with `nil`, and all your code that attempts to get information from this `nil` value will also return `nil`, finally resulting in the product identifier you are passing to `provideContentForProductIdentifier:` being `nil`.

Comment: hey  thanks .....  i deleted my test acc and made a new one and now it all works, must have been a error on the test acc ...

Answer (score 1):

Change the allocation of `_purchasedProductIdentifiers`

replace `_purchasedProductIdentifiers = [NSMutableSet set];`

By `_purchasedProductIdentifiers = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];`

Comment: This worked for me but I'd like to know why it works, if you can explain... My issue wasn't a nil value for _purchasedProductIdentifiers, but was related to my test account "holding on" to some previous purchase attempts.